# PHP Выборка диапазона из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
$array = ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','a','a'];
```

Как его разделить на несколько массивов по делителю - значению массива.
Должно получиться примерно так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )
        
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => a
            [2] => a
            [3] => a
        )

)
```

То есть нужна выборка массива до того, как встретим определенное значение.

Comment: Да банально циклом проходится можно......и отрезать элемент от предыдущего индекса до текущего.......в новый массив

Answer (score 1):

как-нибудь так будет

```
$data = [....];
$needle = 'b';
$idx = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
   $result[$idx][] = $value;
   $idx += ($value == $needle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','a','a'];
$needle = 'b';
$idx = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
   $result[$idx][] = $value;
   $idx += ($value == $needle);
}
```

Comment: Фактически это дубликат более раннего ответа от `teran`